# How to send a SNMP-Packet via UDP

Tags: c, snmp

The idea of my socket is receiving and sending SNMP-packets - `GetRequest/GetResponse`. However, the socket already receive SNMP-packets

```
...
unsigned char buf[8192];
...
for (;;) {
  // Receive snmp message from snmp manager
  recv_len = recvfrom(my_socket, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr
*)&remote_addr, &addr_len);
...
```

Now I want answer the request by a SNMP-Packet which is represents as string. Note: The response contains a `GetResponse-PDU` (`a2`).

```
unsigned char * packet = "302902010004067075626c6963a21c...";
int r = sendto(my_socket, packet, strlen(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, addr_len);
```

The return value or `r` is `4` and is definitely wrong because my responding SNMP-packet `packet` is larger than 4. Why, because it's a pointer?.

Further, the response SNMP-Packet `packet` is not send as SNMP-Packet, it looks different compare to `packet` and is not interpret as a SNMP-Packet in Wireshark. It looks like that:

[image]

How can I send a valid SNMP-Packet?

Comment: If you are working on Linux you can use `libsnmp-dev` an SNMP library. You can use API's of that library to create an SNMP packet.
But you need to find out how to use it.

Comment: Yes, I work on Linux, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @GauravPathak Do you know where I can find the sources or a documentation of `libsnmp-dev`?

Comment: [Here](http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html)

Comment: Do you want to natively develop SNMP server? Why not use Net-SNMP which supports tons of features and mostly complaint with all types of SNMP agents.

Comment: @MilindDeore Because, net-snmp library supports more than I need. My native (Fake) SNMP-Agent will support SNMPv1 only. Further, SNMP is a simple protocol and I thought it can not be problem to send a valid SNMP-Packet in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the strlen(packet) value, which is 4 due to the 00 byte.
strlen is meant to be used with ASCII strings, not binary strings.